# Java consecutive number search

Tags: java, arrays

i need help with my current hw. We are given a program in which there is a number board from which we check to see if there are 4 consecutive numbers horizontally, vertically, and diagonally. I have done some c++ before and have just started java, unfortunately I don't know where i should get started in this program.

Here's the skeleton for the program that we are given. I need someone to get me started on writing this program by telling me methods to find numbers horizontally, vertically, and diagonally. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
public class A3 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[][] board = 
            {
                {0, 1, 0, 6, 1, 6, 1},
                {0, 1, 6, 8, 6, 0, 1},
                {5, 2, 2, 1, 8, 2, 9},
                {6, 5, 6, 1, 1, 2, 1},
                {6, 5, 6, 2, 3, 9, 1},
                {3, 5, 6, 6, 9, 8, 9},
                {6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3},
                {1, 3, 5, 1, 9, 6, 7}    
            };

            System.out.println(isConsecutiveFour(board));

    }

    public static boolean isConsecutiveFour(int[][] values) 
    {   
        return (isConsecutiveFourInHorizontal(values)   ||
                isConsecutiveFourInVertical(values)     ||
                isConsecutiveFourInDiagonalLeft(values) ||
                isConsecutiveFourInDiagonalRight(values));
    }

    public static boolean isConsecutiveFourInHorizontal(int[][] values) 
    {
        boolean result = false;  
        return result;
    }

    public static boolean isConsecutiveFourInVertical(int[][] values) 
    {
        boolean result = false;
        return result;
    }

    public static boolean isConsecutiveFourInDiagonalLeft(int[][] values) 
    {
        boolean result = false;
        return result;
    }

    public static boolean isConsecutiveFourInDiagonalRight(int[][] values) 
    {
        boolean result = false;
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: This just a 2d array. No different than in any other language.

Comment: Try actually doing the assignment and then come back with a more specific question if you encounter problems. As is, you're basically just asking people to do your assignment for you. If you really don't know where to start at all then I suggest reviewing your course notes or talking to your professor/TA during office hours.

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem down- you want a method to check for horizontals, then verticals, then diagonals.

Consider what it means for four numbers to be in a horizontal , vertical, etc

in psuedocode, I'd write

```
checkhorizontal=
for i  in board.height -1
    for j in board.width - 5
    int v = board[i][j]
        for k in 3
        if board [i][j+k] == V+1 
        v++
           if k = 2 
           return true
return false
```